# How to add new tokens into PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to add some more tokens such as OPEN into PostgreSQL, what procedure should I follow? I did not find corresponding documents. thanks.

Comment: And what should `OPEN` do? Do you want to extend the functionality of Postgres? Where do you use that "token"? What problem are you trying to solve by extending Postgres?

Comment: yes, I want to extend functionality of Psql. I want to add more tokens with corresponding functions into psql. OPEN is just an example, I want to add more of them.

Comment: Why do you think you need a new "token"? If you just need to write a database function, [this manual page on "User-defined functions"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc.html) is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming you mean "the postgresql server" not "the command line client `psql` and that by "Token" you mean "SQL command / statement type"):

... yeah, that's not super simple.

If it's a utility command that does not require query planning it isn't super hard. You can take the existing utility commands as guidance on how they work. They're all quite different though. Start with `ProcessUtility`.

If it's intended to produce a query plan, like `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `CREATE TABLE AS`, etc ... well, that tends to be a lot more complicated.

This sort of thing will require some quality time reading the PostgreSQL source code and [developer documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/internals.html). It's way too complex to give you a step-by-step how-to here, especially since you have not even explained what the command you wish to add is supposed to do.

If at all possible you should develop the functionality you need as a user defined function first. Start with PL/PgSQL, PL/Perl, or whatever, and if you hit the limitations of that develop it as a C extension.

Once you have all the functionality you want as C functions, *then* think about whether it makes sense to extend the actual SQL syntax.